# Getting undefined when updating many using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node.js application which uses Mongoose.js to interface with MongoDB. I am trying to have it so that when a certain action happens (updating a plan) that it then updates all user's with a certain companyID (ie all users who belong to that company). Below my code returns undefined for how many found as well as how many updated.

```
const updated = User.updateMany({ companyID: req.body.companyID }, { 'company.stripe.plan': req.body.plan });
console.log(updated.n)
console.log(updated.nModified)
```

req.body

```
{ company:
   { stripe:
      { plan: '<>',
        subscriptionId: '<>',
        customerId: '<>',
        last4: '<>' },
     companyName: '<>'},
  isVerified: true,
  _id: '<>',
  email: '<>',
  companyID: 'fc5a653c-2f68-4925-9ff2-93fde2157453',
  updatedAt: '2020-02-10T01:32:53.510Z',
  createdAt: '2020-02-04T00:44:27.971Z',
  __v: 0,
  lastLogin: '2020-02-10T00:46:16.118Z',
  plan: '<>',
  subscriptionId: '<>' }
```

I've redacted some info that isn't needed and probably shouldn't be shared. The first part of the req.body is actually a single user being sent to the API along with the plan and subscriptionId seen at the bottom.

My console.log seen in my first snippet are returning undefined when I would expect it to return 2 records found and 2 updated/modified.

EDIT**
Seeing as it wasn't clear here is my minified User model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    companyID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },


    company: {
        stripe: {
            customerId: String,
            subscriptionId: String,
            last4: String,
            plan: {
                type: String,
                default: 'default'
            },
        }
    },
    lastLogin: Date,
    lastChangedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
```

Function with all but the needed removed

```
exports.plan = function(req, res, next) {
...
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.body.companyID)
    const updated = User.updateMany({ companyID: req.body.companyID }, { 'company.stripe.plan': req.body.plan });
    console.log(updated.n)
    console.log(updated.nModified)
    return res.json({success: true})
....
}
```

Comment: Are you properly waiting on DB calls, means you need to wait until updateMany is done & then print `updated`, it might result in an error if it surpasses though..Did you parse your request ? Can you give your other parts of code..

Comment: What do you mean 'properly waiting on DB calls'? I have other code that runs before and after perfectly fine so this DB call shouldn't be an issue. I also checked the DB and it is in fact not updating so it's not a matter of JS being async I think. Request is parsed and I am 100% sure the data I am trying to pass in from req.body is correct. What other parts of my code? This is part of a good chunk and code I don't think is needed or feel comfortable sharing.

Comment: @joshj132 : Do you mean to say you've executed same query on DB ? & it worked on not ?

Comment: @whoami No not the same query, the query might be the issue, idk. I have ran a DB just before this DB call and I run another one ~20 lines down as well, both of those other ones work. The one in my OP doesn't work

Comment: You need to differentiate between DB query issue or code issue !! You need to try to execute this query on DB & check if it's properly executing then need to check the code !! To check the code what you've provided is not enough !! If you don't feel good to share few parts like model, few line of the function & also sample docs then it seems not that easy to solve this  !!

Comment: @whoami Whoah... Okay so I can check the DB and see it should return what I said it should. I've provided enough to debug this, if you want the model look at my req.body snippet and see everything except the last 2 lines, that is my user model with a bunch of stuff removed to make it clearer. The important parts - the one I am querying on and the one I am updating - are untouched. What does providing my function do? The mongoose part is the issue not my function... What sample doc are you referring to?

Comment: @whoami Here is the only doc that might be of use, it is the mongoose docs for this query / update https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany

Comment: @whoami Just ran a DB query and as I expected the DB query passes. I did `{companyID: "<the company ID found by console.log above>"}`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, issue was the key in the key/value for the update, it was not working with dot notation however when I switched to bracket notation is is now working. I think this might be a limitation of mongoose as I have a feeling I ran into this error before.